# Mobile and Desktop site switch

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile

I have two different codeigniter CMS for desktop and mobile versions of site. I use codeigniter user agent to detect mobile and redirect to mobile version. I have a link in mobile site to browse the desktop version as well. I used session and cookie separately, one by one in mobile cms and tried to get those values in desktop cms but it was different cms so not possible. How can I switch from mobile to desktop condition there codeigniter user agent is also enabled.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two sites are under the same domain ( eg `www.site.com` and `mobile.site.com` ), you can have cookies that are available for both, by specifying their domain with a leading period ( ie `.site.com` ).

That way you can access the cookies from both sites, and if your cookies are the session cookies, you can have a common session as well.

For CodeIgniter, you can use the setting :

```
 $config['cookie_domain']    = ".site.com";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I couldn't solve it since I am new to session and cookies. I use a function in mobile site, it first sets session or cookies in it and then redirects to desktop version. But the same session value or cookie value is not present in desktop site.

Comment: @user1609828: That's an option in CodeIgniter config file :P